# Some 3rd party controls are not always accessable in UI Automation

Tags: microsoft-ui-automation, ranorex

I am using Ranorex to do automation tests against our application, which consists of several 3rd party controls, like the DevExpress GridControl. In most cases the grid rows are accessible. However, it can happen that the grid rows are not accessible (for about 1 minute), only if you play with Ranorex Spy for a some time.

Do you know where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. Does that mean that the grid can be recognized after one minute and that only happens with Ranorex Spy. What if you run the test?
You wrote that it happen sometimes, did you already find out when?

Is there a difference when using the external Spy and the Spy which is integrated in Ranorex Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to this question, but I've found that grid size can have a big impact on this. As far as I can tell, it's not that the rows and cells are "not accessible", it's that Ranorex is trying to load *all* of them before showing you info about them, and while this works fine on small grids, it apparently doesn't scale well. Try running your tests on smaller data sets.